# Angular $q service implementation in run method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an example that loads some data from local files by global `loadJSON` function (being global is not compulsory but preferable).

After that I wait while data from all documents is loaded and print `'i ve loaded'` string.

The problem is that I start using data from 'x' service earlier than I manage to fully upload it into memory from the files.

How do I wait until data is loaded and only after that continue to rendering the pages and executing everything?

Prob I need to use `$q` for that but how do i do it?

```
function loadJSON(file, callback) {
  var doc = new XMLHttpRequest();
  doc.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  doc.open('GET', file, true);
  doc.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (doc.readyState == 4 && doc.status == "200") {
      callback(JSON.parse(doc.responseText));
    }
  };
  doc.send(null);
}

angular
  .module('msApp')
  .factory('service.x', [
    function () {
      var _database = {};

      return {
        get: function (k1, k2) {
          return _database[k1][k2];
        },

        load: function (list, callback) {
          var length = list.length;
          var loaded = 0;

          function addToDB(name) {
            var url = './assets/{0}.json'.format(name);
            loadJSON(url, function (json) {
              _database[name] = json;

              loaded++;
              if (length === loaded && callback) callback();
            });
          }

          for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            addToDB(list[i]);
          }
        }

      };
    }
  ]);

angular
  .module('msApp', [])
  .run([
    '$rootScope',
    'service.x',
    function ($rootScope, x) {

      x.load($rootScope.services, function () {
        console.log('i ve loaded')
      });

    }
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
      .when('/sign', {
        templateUrl: '../views/sign.html',
        controller: 'signCtrl'
      })
      .when('/a', {
        templateUrl: '../views/a.html',
        controller: 'aCtrl'
          .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/signin'
          });
  });
```

Comment: why are you not using $http to load the data

Comment: do not see how its connected to the question. Becouse system uses this method. i just copied a part that is required by question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

controllers accept a `resolve` parameter which allows you to inject dependencies into the controllers that can be raw objects or promises which blocks the instantiation of the controller until it is resolved:

```
$routeProvider.when('/routeA', {
  templateUrl: '/routeA.html',
  controller: 'controllerA',
  resolve: {
    mydata: ['service.x', function (x) {
      return x.load($rootScope.services);
    }]
  }
});
```

the `load` and `addToDb` functions needs to be modified to return promises:

```
load: function (list) {
  // instantiate variables

  function addToDb(name) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    // build url from name

    loadJson(url, function (data) {
      // save to database

      deferred.resolve(data);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }

  var promises = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    promises.push(addToDb(list[i]));
  }

  return $q.all(promises);
}
```